# Using d3 instead of jQuery to process form input causes re-load of "/"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom-events

Gist http://bl.ocks.org/gregsgit/7cbe5a54fdae2492a826
or https://gist.github.com/gregsgit/7cbe5a54fdae2492a826

I'm trying to use only d3 instead of d3 and jQuery.
Back end is node.js + express + http + fs + socket.io.
Front end uses socket client side, d3, jQuery.

Replacing the following:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  socket.emit('sent message', $('#theInput').val());
  $('#theInput').val('');
  return false;
});
```

with

```
d3.select("#theForm").on("submit", function() {
  var inp = d3.select("#theInput");
  var v = inp.property("value");
  inp.property("value", "");
  socket.emit('sent message', v);
  return false;
});
```

causes a re-load of "/", which removes that state I accumulated in index.html.

In other words, in the node top-level, multidraw-server.js, I print to the console when "/" is requested. With the jquery code, "/" is loaded once, and I can submit the form multiple times without reloading. With the d3 form processing, "/" is re-loaded after every form input.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try using `d3.event.preventDefault()` at the start of your `onsubmit` function?

Comment: Glad to help! I added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you need to cancel the form's submission in addition to returning `false`, which can be done by calling [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault). You can do this with D3 by calling `d3.event.preventDefault()` at the beginning of your `.on("submit", ...)` function.